# Nginx not captures regex variables

Tags: nginx, configuration, regex

Trying to capture URLs like http://mydomain/1234567890123 (13 digits)

```
        location ~ ^/([\d]{13})$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/product?id=$1;
    }
```

$1 variable arriving empty, even if URL is being captured.
What am I missing?

P.S. Tried also named variables. Not helps.

Comment: Try using a map.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille why? What is the difference?

Comment: One of the differences is that maps work.

Answer (score 0):

An extract from a working configuration using a map:

```
map $uri $maptest {
    "~^(?<folder1>.*?)/?(\?.*)?$" page-cache$folder1/1.html;
}

server {
        location /node_direct/ {
          proxy_pass http://nodeServers/$maptest;
        }
}
```